# Use PHP to change certain page content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I need help on my site http://clubs.dundaah.com, it has a slide out menu that lists clubs in the city. What I'm looking for is code for when a club is clicked on it should display that club's info and gmap location without changing the current HTML doc. 
this is the club menu

```html
<div class="slideout-menu">
 <h3>More Clubs <a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">&times;</a></h3>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Aqua Blu Club  <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bachus Lounge<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Choices<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Fahreheit <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hypnotica  <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>

 </ul>
</div>
```

this is the div that i want to change once a club is clicked on above,

```html
<div id="three-column">
   <div class="tbox1">
    <div class="box"> 
    <img draggable="false" align="middle" src="img/blog/1.png" alt="Dundaah" width="400px" height="200px"><br>
     <div id="onclick1" onClick="openClose('a1')" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer;  font-size:14pt"><b>This is Club info</b></div>
     <div id="a1" class="texter">
         <p><h4>This is the hidden text that was revealed when the header was clicked. Such hidden text is generally
         related to the main header which opens them. You can add any number of collapsible headers.</h4> </p> 
         <img draggable="false" align="middle" src="img/blog/1.jpg" alt="Dundaah" width="400px" height="200px">
         <p><h4>Clicking on the header when the text is seen hides the text. Additionally if a header is clicked it will automatically
         close any open text related to any other header while opening its own hidden text.</h4></p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="tbox2">
   
    <script class="javasth" type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script><div style="overflow:hidden;height:400px;width:450px;"><div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:400px;width:450px;"><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" /> </div><style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style><a class="google-map-code" href="http://premium-wordpress-themes.org" id="get-map-data">templates wordpress premium</a></div><script type="text/javascript"> function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:14,center:new google.maps.LatLng(40.805478,-73.96522499999998),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.805478, -73.96522499999998)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:"<b>The Breslin</b><br/>2880 Broadway<br/> New York" });google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>
   </div>
   
  </div>
```

this is because there is a back button that redirects users to the previous page before they land on the site clubs.dundaah.com. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: use google's friend the ajax

Comment: do you mean change in the sense page not being reloaded when we click on the menu

Comment: use ajax @Max Njoroge

Comment: yes the page should not relaod @xenish

Answer (score 0):

ok so first change the selection menu to a select and size it and change the small things in css

```
<select> 
  <option value="" >select..</option>
  <option value="Aqua_Blu" >Aqua Blu Club</option>
  <option value="Bachus" >Bachus Lounge</option>
  <option value="Choices" >Choices</option>
  <option value="Fahreheit" >Fahreheit</option>
  <option value="Hypnotica" >Hypnotica</option>
```

then to make the right thing show up and not you use this JS

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.divAquaInfo').hide();
        $('.divBachusInfo').hide();
        $('.divChoicesInfo').hide();
        $('.divFahreheitInfo').hide();
        $('.divHypnoticaInfo').hide();
   $('select[name=deptSelect]').change(function(){
    if ($('select[name=deptSelect]').val() == 'Aqua_Blu'){
        $('.divAquaInfo').show();
        $('.divBachusInfo').hide();
        $('.divChoicesInfo').hide();
        $('.divFahreheitInfo').hide();
        $('.divHypnoticaInfo').hide();

    }
    if ($('select[name=deptSelect]').val() == 'Bachus'){
        $('.divAquaInfo').hide();
        $('.divBachusInfo').show();
        $('.divChoicesInfo').hide();
        $('.divFahreheitInfo').hide();
        $('.divHypnoticaInfo').hide();

    }
            if ($('select[name=deptSelect]').val() == 'Choices'){
        $('.divAquaInfo').hide();
        $('.divBachusInfo').hide();
        $('.divChoicesInfo').show();
        $('.divFahreheitInfo').hide();
        $('.divHypnoticaInfo').hide();

    }
            if ($('select[name=deptSelect]').val() == 'Fahreheit'){
        $('.divAquaInfo').hide();
        $('.divBachusInfo').hide();
        $('.divChoicesInfo').hide();
        $('.divFahreheitInfo').show();
        $('.divHypnoticaInfo').hide();
    }
            if ($('select[name=deptSelect]').val() == 'Hypnotica'){
        $('.divAquaInfo').hide();
        $('.divBachusInfo').hide();
        $('.divChoicesInfo').hide();
        $('.divFahreheitInfo').hide();
        $('.divHypnoticaInfo').show();

      }
  }
  );    
 </script>
```

Comment: some of my syntax and stuff is probably messed sorry its too early for this stuff

Comment: hey sam b thanks but it didn't work for me, the select part changes a lot of things

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this just a simple example to help you. The code may not have the best practises still I hope it will help you
Use Ajax to  retrieve data

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"> </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#selector").click(function() {                

      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to youPhpfile.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "yoururl", //your created url            
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){                    
            $("#yourContent").html(response); 
        }

    });
});
});
<script>
```

Your php code may be something like this

```
<?php
include("connection.php"); //Do create a database commection

mysql_select_db("yourdbname",$con);
$result=mysql_query("select * from yourTable",$con);

echo '<p>' //Just Assuming the html to be say a p tag

while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{   
    echo "Create your html here ";
}

echo "</p>"

?>
```

For html part lets assume just a div

```
<div id="yourContent">
 //This is where the content will be displayed
</div>
```

Comment: i haven't stored the info in a DB but thanks for the idea. how do i activate the js function above

Comment: it gets activated whenever any DOM element with say id selector ( in the above case) is clicked you could change the selector as per your need https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ have a look at the selectors you have and also via ajax the page doesnot reload and you still get your data from database have a look about this here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ @MaxNjoroge